# How to check if the form has at minimum one input that has data Angular 2+ Form Validation

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a form in angular with 2 input and 2 checkbox and the button next: the button next should be clickable only if one of the input is bind with data and one of the checkbox is checked. So no matter which input or which checkbox one of them is a must.

```
   <form #personalForm="ngForm" class="editForm" novalidate>

        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10'>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6'>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label form-label" for="email">Email</label>
                            <input class="form-control input-md form-input" id="name" name="email" #email="ngModel" required pattern="^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]{2,}$"
                                id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="customer.email" #spy>
                            <div class="alert alert-danger" [hidden]="email.valid">Email is required and must be valid</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6'>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label form-label" for="phone">Phone Number</label>
                            <input class="form-control input-md form-input"  #phone="ngModel" required id="phone" name="phone" type="text"
                                (keypress)="keyPress($event)" minlength=10 maxlength=10 [(ngModel)]="customer.phone">
                            <div class="alert alert-danger" [hidden]="phone.valid">Phone Number is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class='row'>
                    <div class="btn-group btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                        <label class="btn active">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="checkboxOne" #testEmail="ngModel" required name="test" [(ngModel)]="personal.testEmail">
                            <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-2x"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-2x"></i>Email

                        </label>
                        <label class="btn active">
                            <input type="checkbox" #testSMS="ngModel" required name="test" [(ngModel)]="personal.testSMS" value="E-Mail">
                            <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-2x"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-2x"></i>SMS                 
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="divReqEmail" style="color:red" [hidden]="testEmail.valid"> * test Email or SMS is required</div>
                <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <button uiSref="result" class="btn btn-default btn-outline-rounded btn-info" [disabled]="!personalForm.valid" (click)="save(personalForm)">
                        Next
                        <span style="margin-left:10px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a custom validation on the typescript.You can use two arrays to store the values of input and checkbox. Use the length of arrays to bind the `disabled` property of `Next` button.

Comment: can you show me an example? I'm really new to angular.

Comment: since you already have the local variables in place `#email="ngModel`, you can achieve the functionality by replacing `[disabled]="!((testSMS.valid || testEmail.valid) && (phone.valid || email.valid))"` in the button

Comment: seems working, the only problem is with the checkbox that if you checked and unchecked one is impacting in the button. Thank you

Comment: You can mark it as answer and upvote if you like. Thanks :)